# Trying to process information from .csv file into PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I'm trying to pull information from a .CSV file to process with PHP into a local database.

I have the following code:

```
<?
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('red.csv'));
echo $csv[1];
?>
```

The first bit works, if I try to echo the array_map with print_r or var_dump - but I'm not sure how to process it this way.
I'm used to being able to loop through with a for loop where $csv is an array and [0] is the record - but right now the only thing being `ECHO`'d is `Array`

I've never worked with array_map's before - and I found the code I am using (Except for the echo obviously) elsewhere online.

How can I loop through the entire array to process each record individually?

Comment: `$csv[1]` is the array of values for that row. Whenever you are unsure what a variable is, use `var_dump($var)` to get a nice representation. Then you'll know how to work with it.

Comment: @dan08 I tried that, it's just that the array is 3000 records, so I couldn't make much sense of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `Array` is being `echo`ed is because `str_getcsv` returns an array. So `$csv` is an array with each element inside it being an array of the csv values. If you change it to

```
<?php
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('red.csv'));
print_r($csv[0]);
?>
```

You will be able to see the line as an array of each csv item.

Comment: So I can do `echo $csv[0][1];` to get the 2nd record inside the 1st record?

Comment: That is what is should be. If it isn't working that way, and seems like the file isn't getting read properly, add `ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);` before you read the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through csv with this:

```
if (($handle = fopen("your.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, null, ";", '"')) !== FALSE) {
        // $data is an array that contains the current row
    }
}
```

note: change the delimiter and escape characters in fgetcsv() according to your csv.

Answer (score 0):

You can travel/iterate over the CSV array using this structure:

```
foreach( $csv as $row_id => $row_data ) {
    foreach( $row_data as $cell_id => $cell_data ) {
         // The next will output the same data
         echo $cell_data . '\n';
         echo $csv[$row_id][$cell_id] . '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below code for getting data from csv, looping through each row.

```
<?php
    $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('red.csv'));
    //print_r($csv[0]);
    foreach($csv as $key=>$v)
    { 
    echo $csv[$key][0];//column A/0
    echo $csv[$key][1];//column B/1
    }
    ?>
```